# Drooping peace lilly! Is it ok?

Tags: plant-health, plant-recommendations, fertilizer, peace-lily

My peace Lilly is drooping and has brown/ yellow spots. is it overwatering or too dry ? I watered it last week But it was also recently fertilized. The soil is a bit moist around the stems but mainly dry. It doesn’t even have drainage system.

Comment: You cannot overwater Spathiphyllum, as it sits happily in a dish of water. A rare plant that blooms in very low light. Fertilize less, please. Leftover tea or black coffee, okay.